# Apache Camel : Call to .bean not saving object in DB

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am writing a simple POC using Apache Camel to receive SMNP traps.  I am trying to take the incoming exchange message, convert it to `SnmpMessage` and then create a custom type that holds two fields from the `SnmpMessage`.  I then want to save this custom object to an H2 DB.  My SNMP route looks like this:

```
open class SnmpTrapRoute(private val repository: IPduEventRepository) : RouteBuilder() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure() {

        from("snmp:0.0.0.0:1611?protocol=udp&type=TRAP")
                .process { exchange ->
                    val message = exchange.getIn() as SnmpMessage
                    val pduEvent = CustomPduEvent(message.snmpMessage.requestID.toLong(), message.snmpMessage.type)
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(pduEvent, CustomPduEvent::class.java)
                }
                .bean(repository, "save")
                .log("MIH :: DB Entries [" + repository.findAll() + "]")
    }
}
```

However, the `.bean` call doesn't seem to add the object to the DB.  If I include `repository.save(pduEvent)` in the processor and remove the call to `.bean`, it adds it fine.

Have also tried setting the out message body `exchange.out.setBody(pduEvent, PduEvent::class.java)` but same result.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe the `bean` component does not call the "save" method as your expectation. Try add a log in the "save" method and check it.

Comment: Thanks @hk6279.  Yeah it is getting called.  The issue appears to be the `exchange.getIn().setBody(pduEvent, CustomPduEvent::class.java)` calls.  On the `.bean` call, the body doesnt appear to have changed at all.  The exchange is still the same `SnmpMessage` as the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I had two main problems.  Firstly, I needed to set the body of the out message, not the in, and secondly, the final `.log` call didn't work when calling a bean method.  So the call to the bean method was working, but the log call was making it look like it didn't.  So instead I called my logger from within a `process` call.

```
    from("snmp:0.0.0.0:1611?protocol=udp&type=TRAP")
            .process { exchange ->
                val message = exchange.getIn() as SnmpMessage
                exchange.out.body = CustomPduEvent(message.snmpMessage.requestID.toLong(), message.snmpMessage.type)
            }
            .bean(repository, "save")
            .process {
                logger.debug("MIH :: DB Entries [" + repository.findAll() + "]")
            }
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. However, remember that calling 'getOut()' creates a completely new message. [Docs here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html). Perhaps that's what helped you with the right bean binding!

Comment: Thanks @ShellDragon.  I increased my Camel version and IntelliJ then suggested I change `exchange.out` to `exchange.message`, so hopefully that just changes the message rather than creates a completely new one.

Comment: I had a look at `DefaultExchange.java`:339 Camel v3.0.0-M4, `getMessage()` internally invokes`getOut()`, if it is present.

`
   public Message getMessage() {
        return hasOut() ? getOut() : getIn();
    }
`